# Si en una variable tengo XY de php

Tags: php

Si en una variable tengo el valor **juanaksjdhasjteslakdhak** y quisiera que php detecte la letra **u** y salga como lo puedo realizar? para usar esta sentencia con palabras NO deseadas? uso actualmente php 5.6 quiero que sea algo asi como cuando uno busca en una variable mysql pero en php.

Ejemplo que sirve en SQL server o MySQL

```
DECLARE 
@nombre varchar (250) = 'juanaksjdhasjteslakdhak'-- esta variable es infinita
IF (@nombre like'%a%')
print 'contiene el caracter o palabra'
else
print 'Sigio normalito
```

'

Quiero algo asi:

```
$var ="noososjsjdaksdhakdshakjjjdggyosepgJuan";

    IF ( $var like == '%y%') {
    die ('Muere por que el archivo tiene la latra Y y esta palabra o letra no es permitida');
    }else{
    echo "Sigio normalito";
    }
```

Comment: Revisa la función [`mb_strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strpos).

Answer (score 0):

#### En PHP 7 o anterior

Como bien dice @Sal, puedes usar [`mb_strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strpos), por ejemplo:

```
$var ="noososjsjdaksdhakdshakjjjdggyosepgJuan";

if ( mb_strpos($var, 'y')) {
    die ('Muere por que el archivo tiene la letra Y y esta palabra o letra no es permitida');
}else{
    echo "Sigio normalito";
}
```

#### En PHP 8+

A partir de PHP 8, puedes usar la nueva función [`str_contains()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-contains.php):

```
$var ="noososjsjdaksdhakdshakjjjdggyosepgJuan";

if ( str_contains($var, 'y')) {
    die ('Muere por que el archivo tiene la letra Y y esta palabra o letra no es permitida');
}else{
    echo "Sigio normalito";
}
```

#### Polyfill ([fuente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-contains.php#125977))

Y, puedes también hacer una especie de Polyfill, para que te funcione en versiones anteriores a PHP 8. Esto es particularmente interesante si estás escribiendo tu propia biblioteca utilitaria y quieres garantizar la compatibilidad.

Primero escribes esto, que definirá tu propia `str_contains` cuando estés en PHP 7 -.

```
if (!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains($haystack, $needle) {
        return $needle !== '' && mb_strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false;
    }
}
```

Y podrás usar luego `str_contains()` sin importar la versión de PHP.

Esta prueba, en PHP anterior a la versión 8 funciona:

```
$var ="noososjsjdaksdhakdshakjjjdggyosepgJuan";

if ( str_contains($var, 'y')) {
    die ('Muere por que el archivo tiene la letra Y y esta palabra o letra no es permitida');
}else{
    echo "Sigio normalito";
}
```

Comment: la ultima no es para version php8+?

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez la última es para cualquier versión. La primera parte de ese bloque definiría una función `str_contains` (en caso de no existir dicha función), pero que usa `mb_strpos`, por eso este bloque: `if (!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains($haystack, $needle) {` Esto es útil sobre todo en contextos donde quieras garantizar la compatibilidad, como una librería por ejemplo donde escape a tu control en qué versión de PHP correrá el código.